# Wallet 2.5.7- latest snapshot - unknown new addresses between old addresses

Tags: snapshot

Yesterday I tried restore my balances in wallet 2.5.7 after the latest snapshot. I have two seeds. Final balances from both seeds were finally displayed correctly (although once wallet show request error).

However, what is weird to me, that number of addresses, which I had to generate was larger then I expected. I have 6 addresses with iotas "on one seed", but I had to generate 7 addresses to reach final balance. One address (with zero balance) wallet generated between old addresses on which I have my iotas. This new address I saw yesterday for the first time. Similarly it was happen for second seed. I have 2 addresses on which I have iotas. However, I had to generate 4 addresses to reach final correct balance. Two new addresses, which I saw yesterday for first time (with zero balances) were generated between old addresses on which I have funds. After previous snapshot, I normally generated correct number of addresses to reach final correct balance. Generation of addresses from seed is deterministic.

How is possible to see new addresses if I ever generated only addresses on which I have funds. Can someone explain this? Does someone experience same thing?

Below are unknown addresses generated from two seeds:
HCUGZXZYLVTZFK9ZILIKDIMXMZ9GGFWSXOMHTTDTWWPBYLNTXCBWHOJRZNBRWMEPMRCVDFTONOMTRONU9FTZTOTLQX

Unknown addresses from second seed:
ZPUMPJCDTEYDORTSWNNS9HGIPCAGNQIJTTUXMGXJARJCBNGRSALPLTCIIISRQSKVISGBYBZ9IJNHKJDSWF9R9HKEZZ
FNZPEUJOTLZDYSWJMUMCFZTVJOYVKMOXEPIQYUDORCABEJFDI9YHTKLTDCCXVRQDWTBXZMETJFMZROJXZDZA9TOZWW

Comment: Would be interesting which index the unknown addresses were generated from (and which indexes are for the correct addresses). My only guess is that the indexes of the unknown addresses are higher than the indexes of the real addresses and while requesting spent addresses a node had a hiccup and claimed address 6 (for example) to be spent so the wallet generated & attached address 7 first, and then later when the node worked again it generated & attached address 6.